# Linq to sum on groups based on two columns

Tags: linq, group-by, sum, linq-group

I have a class as below:

```
Class Financial
{
    string Debit;
    string Credit;
    decimal Amount;
}
```

And I have a list with objects of this class, with multiple records. All I need is to perform a groupped sum, something like in sql

```
Select debit, Credit, sum(amount) group by Debit, Credit
```

I tried with a statement as below:

```
from operation in m_listOperations
    orderby operation.Debit, operation.Credit ascending
    group operation by operation.Debit, operation.Credit into groupedOperation
    select new Financial(Debit, Credit, 
                groupedOperation.Sum(operation => operation.Amount))
```

But this doesn't work since I cannot group on two columns.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
group operation by new { operation.Debit, operation.Credit } into groupedOperation
...
```